# VC++ Open SSL Build Error

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, openssl

I have a VC++ project in VS 2008 which uses open SSL.
I have installed OpenSSL-Win32. I am compiling the project in 32 bit machine.
While compiling it throws an error as follows,

fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'ssleay32D.lib'

I don't know where this file exists. Am I missing anything here?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer
I have to rename 'ssleay32D.lib' as 'ssleay32MD.lib' in additional dependencies in project properties.

This is because open SSL had a different name in its library folder